# b4a how to parse a json data

Tags: android, json, vb4android

can you help me understand how to parse this one in b4a using jsonparse function. Please i need your help so bad.

```
[{"success":true,"msg":"Your transaction has been successfully Completed. Thank you for having us. Please enjoy our service.","data":[{"fn":"sdf","mn":"sdf","ln":"sdf","contactNum":"324","email":"sdf@sdf.com","regcode":"201635df42e","regDateTime":"2016-3-5 13:43:26","cus_status":"active","tag":"0ec2c07d19095396d49a41796609a6ae"},{"fn":"sdf","mn":"sdf","ln":"sdf","contactNum":"234","email":"sdf@dsaf.com","regcode":"201635d89f1","regDateTime":"2016-3-5 13:43:26","cus_status":"active","tag":"0ec2c07d19095396d49a41796609a6ae"}]}]
```

A cleaner look:

```
 [
{
    "success":true,
    "msg":"Your transaction has been successfully Completed. Thank you for having us. Please enjoy our service.",


    "data":[
        {
            "fn":"sdf",
            "mn":"sdf",
            "ln":"sdf",
            "contactNum":"324",
            "email":"sdf@sdf.com",
            "regcode":"201635df42e",
            "regDateTime":"2016-3-5 13:43:26",
            "cus_status":"active",
            "tag":"0ec2c07d19095396d49a41796609a6ae"
        },
        {
            "fn":"sdf",
            "mn":"sdf",
            "ln":"sdf",
            "contactNum":"234",
            "email":"sdf@dsaf.com",
            "regcode":"201635d89f1",
            "regDateTime":"2016-3-5 13:43:26",
            "cus_status":"active",
            "tag":"0ec2c07d19095396d49a41796609a6ae"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
Dim parser As JSONParser 
parser.Initialize(<text>) 
Dim root As Map = parser.NextObject 
Dim msg As String = root.Get("msg") 
Dim data As List = root.Get("data") 
For Each coldata As Map In data 
 Dim contactNum As String = coldata.Get("contactNum") 
 Dim regDateTime As String = coldata.Get("regDateTime") 
 Dim mn As String = coldata.Get("mn") 
 Dim ln As String = coldata.Get("ln") 
 Dim cus_status As String = coldata.Get("cus_status") 
 Dim fn As String = coldata.Get("fn") 
 Dim regcode As String = coldata.Get("regcode") 
 Dim tag As String = coldata.Get("tag") 
 Dim email As String = coldata.Get("email") 
Next 
Dim success As String = root.Get("success")
```

And this site generate code for your JSON data:
http://www.basic4ppc.com:51042/json/index.html